# CSS background with multiple gradients and a skewed part

Tags: css, background, gradient

I'm trying to create the blue background based on the picture: [multiple css backgrounds with skewed part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh6t2.png)

So far I was able to do either the skew gradient part or the gradient itself.

```
background: linear-gradient(170deg, #031085 80%, #fff 80%); // skew
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #031085 10%, #0F69EF 80%); // linear
```

Do you know how to connect these together to achieve the result on the image?

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(170deg, transparent 80%, #fff 80%)
,linear-gradient(90deg, #031085 10%, #0F69EF 80%)` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif This works, thank you! If you put this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do like below:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(170deg, transparent 80%, #fff 80%),
    linear-gradient(90deg, #031085 10%, #0F69EF 80%)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no multiple gradient background on css. If you want to you can add multi option on background
For Exaple:

```
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/owl1.jpg);
}
```

For more detail you can check this source: https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/

Or

You can add two stacked div tag and you can assign individual backgrounds to them

```
<div class="background1"></div>
<div class="background2"></div>
```